# Banno - Admin API Abilities

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

I was able to find the possible values returned by the *zelle_enabled* Banno Ability. However, I am unsure what each of them means. Can someone please let me know what Send, Request and Split allow a Banno user to do within Zelle?

```
        "name": "zelle_enabled",
        "optional": true,
        "default": null,
        "dataType": "enumeration",
        "enumerationValues": [
            "None",
            "Send",
            "Request",
            "Split",
        ]
```

Comment: Good question. We could do more to add some insight into those values. We'l look into it with Engineering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those values control what functionality within Zelle is available to the end user.

- None: disables Zelle.
- Send: the user can send money but not
  request.
- Request: the user can request money **and** send it.
- Split: not currently supported.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).